# Admin login issue in Magento 2

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, login

I installed Magento 2.1.3 in a2 hosting. After installation I tried to login Admin panel but I failed with a message "***You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.***". I tried with

```
php bin/magento magento admin:user:unlock abu` command  and `UPDATE admin_user a SET a.`failures_num` = 0, a.`first_failure` = NULL, a.`lock_expires` = NULL WHERE a.`username` = 'abu'
```

But I can't login for first time.

Comment: Check your username and password. Also make sure var folder has write permission.

Comment: `I installed Magento 2.1.3 in a2 hosting` => I'm confused about this. Can you explain more?